# Python 2: Passing global variable to factory decorator

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-decorators

In the below script I would like to use the `name_type` global variable in the `decorator` while calling the `get_names` functions. Please don't worry about the program logic.

```
name_type=None
def main():
    global name_type
    name_type="FEMALE"
    get_names()

def superNameDecorator(value):
    def nameDecorator(func):
        if value in ["MALE"]:
            def wrapper1(*args,**kwargs):
                original_result=func(*args,**kwargs)
                modified_result= "<MALE>"+original_result + "<\MALE>"
                return modified_result
            return wrapper1
        elif value in ["FEMALE"]:
            def wrapper2(*args,**kwargs):
                original_result=func(*args,**kwargs)
                modified_result= "<FEMALE>"+original_result + "<\FEMALE>"
                return modified_result
            return wrapper2
    return nameDecorator

@superNameDecorator(name_type)
def get_names():
    name='AMY'
    return name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This works fine when I pass direct string either "MALE"/"FEMALE" but throws below error when passing `name_type`
What am I missing here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GlobalTesting.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "GlobalTesting.py", line 5, in main
    get_names()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `get_names` is defined, `name_type` is `None`, because `main` hasn't been called yet.  Neither of the `if/elif` clauses get run, so `nameDecorator` returns `None`, which gets bound to the identifier `get_names`.  One solution would be to remove `main` and just make it a `__name__` check  near the top of the file.

```
import os
import re
import sys


name_type=None
if __name == '__main__':  # If this doesn't happen, this error will still occur.
    name_type="FEMALE"

def superNameDecorator(value):
    def nameDecorator(func):
        if value in ["MALE"]:
            def wrapper1(*args,**kwargs):
                original_result=func(*args,**kwargs)
                modified_result= "<MALE>"+original_result + "<\MALE>"
                return modified_result
            return wrapper1
        elif value in ["FEMALE"]:
            def wrapper2(*args,**kwargs):
                original_result=func(*args,**kwargs)
                modified_result= "<FEMALE>"+original_result + "<\FEMALE>"
                return modified_result
            return wrapper2
    return nameDecorator

@superNameDecorator(name_type)
def get_names():
    name='AMY'
    return name

if __name == '__main__':
    get_names()
```

A more sensible solution would be to rewrite your `nameDecorator` to handle any `name_type`, and the lack of a `name_type`, in some way that makes sense to you.